# Set variables in c# expression tree

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I am creating a c# expression for basic some basic maths operations, for example:

```
(x + 1) / 2.
```

The expression tree, in this case, will contain one Parameter, two Constants, and two BinaryExpression - one for addition, and the other one for devision. I compile this expression into a delegate and want to execute it for different values of x.
How do I do it?

I use the following methods to create the expression tree

```
var ex1 = Expression.Constant(1, typeof(decimal)); - for constants
var ex2 = Expression.Variable(typeof(decimal), $"x"); - for parameters
Expression.MakeBinary(expressionType, ex1, ex2) - for operations
```

I compile the final expression tree like this:

```
    var le = Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(expression);
    var compiledExpression = le.Compile();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's why it helps to use the actual type instead of `var` when the type isn't obvious. You want a `Func<decimal, decimal>` as your lambda since you want to pass a parameter. Here's an example (used `int` for simplicity):

```
ConstantExpression ex1 = Expression.Constant(1, typeof(int));
ParameterExpression ex2 = Expression.Variable(typeof(int), $"x");
BinaryExpression be = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Add, ex1, ex2);

// you want an expression that takes a parameter
Expression<Func<int, int>> func = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(be, ex2);
Func<int, int> compiledExpression = func.Compile();

// now you have a compiled expression that wants a parameter...
int res = compiledExpression(1);
```

**Update**
Another approach for your use case:

```
ConstantExpression const1 = Expression.Constant(1, typeof(int));
ConstantExpression const2 = Expression.Constant(2, typeof(int));

ParameterExpression var1 = Expression.Variable(typeof(int), $"x");

BinaryExpression assign = Expression.Assign(var1, const2);
BinaryExpression add = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Add, const1, var1);

BlockExpression block = Expression.Block(new List<ParameterExpression>() { var1 }, assign, add);

Expression<Func<int>> func = Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(block);
Func<int> compiledExpression = func.Compile();

int res = compiledExpression();
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction - of course, I was missing the input parameter in my lambda. Additional question, let's say I have multiple input parameters (the number is not predefined), the order of the parameters also not known - how do I assign a value to a specific variable? I.e. in a formula like this (x+1)/(y+2) - I am setting the names of the variables - is there any way to use this name to set them?

Comment: @BashirMagomedov another option is to revert to your original parameter-less lambda and do your variable assignments as part of the expression tree. I'll post an update